# Error with defining member function of a class

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple quadtree code but i get this one error

```
#include<iostream>
class qtree
{

struct node
{
node *left1;node *left2;
char data;
node *right1;node *right2;
}*root;
char *arr;
int *lc1;int *lc2;int *rc1;int *rc2;

public:
qtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int size);
void insert(int index);
static node* buildtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int index);
void display();
static void inorder(node *sr);
~qtree();
static void del(node *sr);
};

qtree::qtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int size)
{
root = NULL;
arr = new char[size];
lc1 = new int[size];lc2 = new int[size];rc1 = new int[size];rc2 = new int[size];

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
*(arr+i)=*(a+i);
*(lc1+i)=*(l1+i);*(lc2+i)=*(l2+i);
*(rc1+i)=*(r1+i);*(rc2+i)=*(r2+i);
}

}

void qtree::insert(int index)
{
root = buildtree(arr,lc1,lc2,rc1,rc2,index);
}

node* qtree :: buildtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int index) //LINE 45
{
node* temp =NULL;
if(index!=-1)
{
temp = new node;
temp->left1 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(l1+index));
temp->left2 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(l2+index)); 
temp->data = *(a+index);
temp->right1 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(r1+index));
temp->right2 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(r2+index));
}
return temp;
}

void qtree::display()
{
inorder(root);
}

void qtree::inorder(node *sr)
{
if(sr!=NULL)
{
inorder(sr->left1);
inorder(sr->left2);
cout<<sr->data<<"\t";
inorder(sr->right1);
inorder(sr->right2);
}
}

qtree::~qtree()
{
delete arr;
delete lc1;
delete lc2;
delete rc1;
delete rc2;
del(root);
}

void qtree::del(node *sr)
{
if(sr!=NULL)
{
del(sr->left1);
del(sr->left2);
del(sr->right1);
del(sr->right2);
}
delete sr;
}

void main()
{

char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'};
int l1[] = {1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int l2[] = {2,6,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int r1[] = {3,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int r2[] = {4,8,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

int sz = sizeof(a);

qtree qt(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,sz);
qt.insert(0);

cout<<"\nThe elements are"<<endl;
qt.display();
}
```

ERROR-
quad_tree.cpp:45: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token

What can be the problem??

**P.S**:I have commented line no 45

Comment: can you please indent your code ?...

Comment: Try `qtree::node *`...

Comment: -1 for poor formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure node is defined only inside qtree class.

If you want to use it outside qtree's methods you should define it outside it.

Otherwise you can use oli's suggestion with

```
qtree:node* qtree::buildtree()
```

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
        node *left1;
        node *left2;
        char data;
        node *right1;
        node *right2;
};

class qtree {

    struct node* root;
    char *arr;
    int *lc1;
    int *lc2;
    int *rc1;
    int *rc2;

public:
    qtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int size);
    void insert(int index);
    static node* buildtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int index);
    void display();
    static void inorder(node *sr);
    ~qtree();
    static void del(node *sr);
};

qtree::qtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int size) {
    root = NULL;
    arr = new char[size];
    lc1 = new int[size];
    lc2 = new int[size];
    rc1 = new int[size];
    rc2 = new int[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        *(arr+i)=*(a+i);
        *(lc1+i)=*(l1+i);
        *(lc2+i)=*(l2+i);
        *(rc1+i)=*(r1+i);
        *(rc2+i)=*(r2+i);
    }

}

void qtree::insert(int index) {
    root = buildtree(arr,lc1,lc2,rc1,rc2,index);
}

node* qtree :: buildtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int index) { //LINE 45
    node* temp =NULL;
    if(index!=-1) {
        temp = new node;
        temp->left1 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(l1+index));
        temp->left2 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(l2+index));
        temp->data = *(a+index);
        temp->right1 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(r1+index));
        temp->right2 = buildtree(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,*(r2+index));
    }
    return temp;
}

void qtree::display() {
    inorder(root);
}

void qtree::inorder(node *sr) {
    if(sr!=NULL) {
        inorder(sr->left1);
        inorder(sr->left2);
        cout<<sr->data<<"\t";
        inorder(sr->right1);
        inorder(sr->right2);
    }
}

qtree::~qtree() {
    delete arr;
    delete lc1;
    delete lc2;
    delete rc1;
    delete rc2;
    del(root);
}

void qtree::del(node *sr) {
    if(sr!=NULL) {
        del(sr->left1);
        del(sr->left2);
        del(sr->right1);
        del(sr->right2);
    }
    delete sr;
}

int main() {

    char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'};
    int l1[] = {1,5,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    int l2[] = {2,6,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    int r1[] = {3,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    int r2[] = {4,8,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

    int sz = sizeof(a);

    qtree qt(a,l1,l2,r1,r2,sz);
    qt.insert(0);

    cout<<"\nThe elements are"<<endl;
    qt.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Plus: you have forgot the **using namespace std** since you use cout later. Use that or replace it with std::cout.

Comment: thanks rob013 rectified th error

Answer (score 0):

```
node* qtree :: buildtree(char *a,int *l1,int *l2,int *r1,int *r2,int index) //LINE 45
```

There's no definition of `node` in scope. You want `qtree::node`.